# Very basic HTML/CSS question- having a link line up with the rest of the sentence

Tags: html, css

So I want to have this:

In association with Company Name

What I'm getting right now is this:

In association with 
Company Name

The company name is a link, but I have my links be red with no underlining by setting them to a class in CSS.

This is the html I have:

```
<a>In association with <div id="bodylinks" class="bodylink"><a href="url.com">Company Name</a></a></div>
```

Here is the CSS associated with bodylink

```
.bodylink a
{
font:  14px Helvetica;
color: red;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

So the company name gets thrown to the next line because it is a different div, how can I avoid this and still use the .bodylink a class to format the link?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

div's are used to create new sections (divisions) in your page. If you don't intend the link to be in a new section, you should remove it and give the  tag the class attribute like this:

```
<a class="bodylink" href="www.example.com">link text</a>
```

You'll also need to change your CSS so it applies to  tags with class bodylink like this:

```
a.bodylink {
  /* styling */
}
```

Comment: great, thank you!  i knew i was using div improperly in this case!

Answer (score 1):

No one bothered to mention that his markup is syntactically incorrect. You can't have the opening anchor tag outside the div, and the closing anchor tag inside.

The div tag is a block level element. You need an inline element, such as a span tag, as others here have suggested.

Comment: Actually, I had mentioned that his markup was syntactically incorrect an hour before you. Everybody just ignored that, including yourself. (^_^)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="bodylink">In association with <a href="url.com">Company Name</a></div>
```

Why do you ahve the whole line anchored? If you use the code above the line in in a div with the class formatting and the Company Name is linked.

Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Try using a span instead, or give the anchor (<a>) itself the class.

Comment: Good point. I was just coming back to my answer so I could add that :P. span's mark of bits of text that are different, but aren't in their own separate section. In this case, I wouldn't use it, since the <a> tag already defines a section of text that has a certain class.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<span>` instead, an inline element that doesn't break the text flow. `<div>` is a block element that creates a "line break" so to speak.

Also, you've got the nesting of your elements all wrong. That's not valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the HTML code should be corrected, as steve_c said.

And to make a div appear inline with other content use the `display: inline;` CSS code on the div you want to appear inline.

Example:

```
the text before div <div style="display: inline;"><a href="#">the link in the text</a></div>
```